# How to mock a method called directly using mockito/powermockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I'm writing a JUnit test case for a method.

**Method**

```
class A extends B {
  public execute() {
    String id = getContext().getid().toString();
  }
}
```

`getContext()` method is defined in class `B`.

How to mock `getContext()`?

Comment: As `getContext()` is present in class `B`, you shouldn't have to mock that method. Usually, you'd provide a context mock from outside via constructor or setter injection into your class, which you'd then access through `getContext()`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how `B` gets the context, which you haven't shown here.

### Dependency Injection

Hopefully, you are using Depenedncy Injection / IoC and `B` looks like:

```
abstract class B {
  private final Context context;

  public B(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }
}
```

Then to inject a mock context into your test, you just pass it into the constructor:

```
public class ATest  {
 @Test
 public void testExecute() {
   // arrange
   Context mockContext = mock(Context.class);
   when(mockContext.getId()).thenReturn(...);
   A a = new A(mockContext);

   // act
   String ret = a.execute()

   // assert
   assertThat(ret).isEqualTo(...);
 }
}
```

### Override the method

One thing you can do in this situation, is to create a subclass of `A` just for testing.
This is messier than the DI approach above, so you should prefer that.

```
public class ATest  {
 private final Context mockContext = mock(Context.class);

 @Test
 public void testExecute() {
   // arrange
   when(mockContext.getId()).thenReturn(...);
   A a = new OpenA(mockContext);

   // act
   String ret = a.execute()

   // assert
   assertThat(ret).isEqualTo(...);
 }

  private class OpenA extends A {
    @Override
    protected Context getContext() {
      return mockContext;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [spy](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.19.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) it:

```
public BTest {
    @Spy
    private B underTest;

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        doReturn(new MySpeicalContext()).when(underTest).getContext();

        // Testing code...
    }
}
```